# Проверка наличия записи из БД в массиве (огромные значения)

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Есть Таблица, порядка 35 тысяч записей. Есть папка с файлами, порядка 132 тысяч изображений

Необходимо перебрать все элементы таблицы и сравнить их названия с картинками в папке. Если в папке файла нет - удалить запись из БД. Изображения имеют в названии разрешение (240х240, 300х300 и подобное).

Есть готовое решение, путем двойного перебора массивов со сравнением названия, но это занимает очень, ну прям ооооочень, много времени, даже при поиске среди 1000 картинок. Как можно ускорить процесс?

Код такой:

```
$db_value = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM s_images");

$src_dir = scandir(_SCDIR,0);
unset($src_dir[0], $src_dir[1]);
if(count($src_dir) == 0) { echo "В папке ". _SCDIR ." изображений нет! <br/>"; }

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_value)) {
    foreach($src_dir as $val) {
        $val = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $val);
        $array = explode(".", $val);
        if (count($array) > 2) {
            unset($array[count($array)-2]);
        }
        $val = implode(".", $array);
        if(!strcasecmp($row['filename'], $val)) {
            $suc++;
        } else {
            $remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'");
        }
        $itr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ускорить перебор, если исправить константу проверки на 2.

Comment: сдается мне только таким вот двойным перебором. вопрос только встает как именно выглядит готовое решение. может просто оно криво написано и логика плохая. лучше посмотреть код........... и еще как минимум выбрать из БД можно неповторяющиеся значения. это как минимум снизит количество 35к в несколько меньшее количество

Comment: повторяющихся значений в БД нет

Comment: вооот, как минимум не надо выбирать select со звездочкой, если в итоге тебе нужно всего лишь поле `filename` и скорее всего `id`....... кроме того, вместо цикла и удаления в цикле, надо выбрать значения, а потом в один или несколько присестов убить при помощи `IN`, причем не по имени, а по идентификатору. Это минимум на что бросается взгляд

Comment: заранее пройдитесь один раз по массиву полученному scandir, подготовьте значения для сравнения, приведите эти значения сразу к одному регистру (раз вы без учета регистра сравниваете). сделайте массив в котором эти значения в одном регистре будут ключами, а не элементами, значением можно поставить например 1. при чтении из БД переводите имя в тот же регистр и просто смотрите нет ли в массиве нужного элемента (isset($arr[$filename]). этим вы исключаете перебор всего массива файлов ради каждого значения из БД

Comment: Интересная мысль. Стоит попробовать

Comment: И еще, если вдруг по полю имя файла нет индекса, то лучше удаляйте по запись id.

Answer (score 0):

Выбирать стоит в SELECT без всех полей, а только ключевые, например:

```
SELECT id, name...
```

Вы так-же в цикле отправляете запрос на удаление из базы, и это тоже тормозит.
Я бы запросы для удаления соединял бы в одну строку, ( не более 50ти запросов в одной строке), и отправлял бы на выполнение.

Вместо

```
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'");
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'");
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'");
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'");
```

У Вас будет один запрос, но в нем будет несколько удалений

```
$str_delete = "DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'";
$str_delete .= "DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'";
$str_delete .= "DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'";
$str_delete .= "DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` = '".$row['filename']."'";
```

Comment: Вообще тогда уж `delete from tab where filename IN('file1','file2',...)`. и дело то не в БД а в том что он ради каждого из 35к входных значений перебирает массив из 132к элементов и того получаем 4.62 миллиарда сравнений

Comment: За выборку спасибо, не подумал. А по поводу перебора, в том то и вопрос, как его сделать более эффективно. Проблема упирается именно во время обработки и количество итераций. Не могу додумать более эффективный способ. Если бы это было разовое исполнение, можно было бы и потерпеть, но планируется раз в неделю исполнять

Answer (score 0):

В общем всем спасибо за отзыв. Исправил, обрабатывает итераций столько, сколько строк в БД. Ну и все остальное тоже ускоренно. Может немного криво конечно, но все же работает.

[Не работает]

Насколько качественно почистит БД - пока не знаю, удаляет записи по 1 в секунду. Но var_dump($filename) вроде не обманул

Comment: замените `array_push($result, $val);` на `$result[$val]=1;`, уберите `$result=array_unique($result);`. замените `if(!in_array($row['filename'], $result)) {` на `if(!isset($result[$row['filename']])) {` получите именно то, что я имел ввиду в коментах, должны получить выигрыш по скорости в десятки раз по сравнению с текущим.

Comment: Спасибо, но он и сейчас обрабатывает все 34к строк менее чем за минуту. Правда все равно попробую, оптимизация должна быть оптимизированной =)

Answer (score 0):

Немного исправлений ошибок. 100% рабочий вариант. Всем спасибо!

```
$db_value = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `filename` FROM s_images");

$src_dir = scandir(_SCDIR,0);
unset($src_dir[0], $src_dir[1]);
if(count($src_dir) == 0) { echo "В папке ". _SCDIR ." изображений нет! <br/>"; }

foreach($src_dir as $val) {
    $val = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $val);
    $array = explode(".", $val);
    if (count($array) > 2) {
        unset($array[count($array)-2]);
    }
    $val = implode(".", $array);
    $result[$val] = 1;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_value)) {
    if(!isset($result[$row['filename']])) {
        array_push($filename, $row['filename']);
    }
    $itr++;
}

echo "Итераций: $itr <br/>";
echo "Будет удалено: ".count($filename)." записей";

$sql = "DELETE FROM `s_images` WHERE `filename` IN('".join("','", $filename)."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```